# Best way to call a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm writing a small example to call function `getAge()` to display age via an object.

I've 3 ways to do that:

```js
"use strict";
var personClass = class {
  static getAge() {
    return 18
  }
};

var personJSON = {
  getAge: function () {
    return 18
  }
};

function personFunc() {
  var getAge = function () {
    return 18
  };
  
  // set a flag to point to getAge function
  this.getAge = getAge()
}

$('#btn1').click(function () {
  alert(personClass.getAge())
});

$('#btn2').click(function () {
  alert(personJSON.getAge())
});

$('#btn3').click(function () {
  var p = new personFunc();
  alert(p.getAge)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Get age via class</button>
<button id="btn2">Get age via json</button>
<button id="btn3">Get age via function</button>
```

My question: What's the best way? And why?

Comment: I'd say the second one, although it has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Nice question. Makes you re-think for a second :)

Comment: I think it depends on what you are doing. Although there could be an interesting/surprising answer.

Comment: A static class level `getAge` func doesn't make much sense, since age is a property of a person (instance), not all person. It really depends on the actual situation...

Comment: This question is either too broad or primarily opinion based. IMO, Your `2nd` is the best way to implement an object in this situation.
Your `3rd` is the best way to confuse the next programmer if that's how you implement more than 1 object.
Your `1st` is the best way to have hundreds of `static getters` without `setters` at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend the most simple form:

```
var personJSON = {
  getAge: function () {
    return 18;
  }
};
```

It already creates a well-defined object with the desired properties, it scales well and it is not encumbered by red-tape boilerplate code.

Good code already did so for years and it is a very well proven style. It is readable and compact.

What you will NOT get from this are the new advanced features of ES6 class definitions which might be required in more advanced cases.

**Warning! This is just my personal, biased opinion:**

> I, for one, will not use class definitions at all, instead I will leverage this style and lambdas, as I've always done in 10+ years. I'm also contrary to the introduction of syntactical sugar in Javascript just to let it look like other languages. I prefer the prototypical paradigm.

Comment: The class syntax is just that: Syntax. So I wonder what those "class features" are that you are talking about.

Comment: I didn't express myself properly. I didn't intend syntactical sugar but getters and setters, which are unrelated. I mixed those up unintentionally, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the actual problem you have to solve and the style of programming you're using. If you tend to use an object oriented approach and want to benfit from it's features like inheritance you might want to model a person as

```
function Person(){
    var age = 18;
    this.getAge = function() {
        return age; 
    }
}

var person = new Person();
alert(p.getAge());
```

Or as a class

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this.age = 18;
  }

  getAge() {
    return this.age()
  }
}
```

If you prefer a more functional style, you'll write pure and independent functions that perform some action on some data:

```
// does not make much sense in this age of a person context
function age(obj, dateFn) {
    return dateFn() - obj.born;
}

var person = { born : new Date(/* */) }
var animal = { born : new Date(/* */) }
alert(age(person, Date.now));
alert(age(animal, Date.UTC));
```

For the example of `getAge`, any kind of static function does not make any sense (your first example), since `age` is the property of some object. So you'll need an instance of an object which you can use to call a method, or to pass to a function.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just saying how I would use the three. This is not meant to be an absolute answer, this is the way I see things. And I'm interested to see other people points of view on this.

### `class`

I'd only use this key word in case I want to instantiate multiple times this object. (Only available in ECMAScript 6)

```
"use strict"
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  speak() {
    console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  speak() {
    console.log(this.name + ' barks.');
  }
}

var bobby = new Dog("Bobby");
bobby.speak();
```

---

### `JSON`

I'd only declare a JSON when I'm only going to instantiate it once.

```
var Game = {
  run: function() {
    //...
  },
  stop: function() {
    //...
  },
  pause: function() {
    //...
  },
  maxPlayer: 4,
  rooms: [{
    roomName: "Room1",
    playerNames: ["Player1", "Player2"]
  }, {
    roomName: "Room2",
    playerNames: ["Player1", "Player2", "Player3"]
  }]
};
```

---

### `function`

You're using it more like a `class` substitute here. By using `new` keyword you can instantiate this function as a class as many times as you want. (Which a lot a people do and that's ok ! Mostly because the keyword `class` is only available in ECMAScript 6)

```
var Person = function (firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
};

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName);
};

var person1 = new Person("Alice");
person1.sayHello();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something like this. I'd be curious to hear other people's feedback.

```
//Convention says use capital case if declaring a function as a class. 
function Person(age){

    //Optional: allow the developer to pass in an age when creating the object
    //Otherwise default to 18
    this.age = age? age: 18;      //ternary operator

    //function declaration. 
    this.getAge = function() {
        return this.age; 
    }

}

$('#btn3').click(function () {
  var p = new Person();
  alert(p.getAge())     //Alert 18

  var p2 = new Person(15);
  alert(p2.getAge())    //Alert 15
});
```

My reasoning for this is that this is an objected oriented way of doing it.

- The capital case lets you know that this function is intended to be used with a with the `new` keyword.
- Is reusable - you can have multiple, different `Person` objects, with different ages, without having to declare the methods each time for each one.
- Syntax and usage is similar to object oriented languages like Java which one might already be familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

The last way that you wrote is the best

```
function personFunc() {
  var getAge = function () {
    return 18
  };

  // set a flag to point to getAge function
  this.getAge = getAge()
}
```

Buth there is a better one by perfomance, but little complex by writing. It is like TypeScript or Babel compiles it's classes to JavaScript.

```
function PersonClass() {  
   this.age = 18;
}

PersonClass.prototype.getAge = function () {
 return this.age;
};
```

usage is the same:

```
var person = new PersonClass();
person.getAge();
```

But to write like this by yourself is little time-consuming. So I think that the best thing for now is to use ES6 classes and compile them with TypeScript or Babel.

So, my opinion is the best way to write like this:

```
class PersonClass {
   private age = 18; 
   getAge() {
      return this.age;
   }
}
```

Comment: If we're going for performance only, he should just write `alert(18)`;

Comment: I'd rather add a `constructor` to `PersonClass`. Because the age is not unique to all Persons, we should be able to change it at least via a setter.

Comment: TypeScript will add constructior for us :)